# Find and replace text in array

Tags: php, replace, find

Using PHP I need to itinerate an array to remove the last **two slash** of every value from this:

```
$my_array = array(
     'http://apinmo.com/1/2/3.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/4/5/8.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/10/9/3.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/76/534535/6-1.jpg'
);
```

to this:

```
$my_new_array = array(
     'http://apinmo.com/123.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/458.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/1093.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/765345356-1.jpg'
);
```

How can get this?

Comment: Right, and how's that going?

Comment: Why the downvote? Can anyone downvote a question without a real cause here?

Comment: Because your question shows no effort, and basically says "this is what I want; who can do it for me?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this with `regex` by removing `/` between the digits.

```
$my_array = array(
     'http://apinmo.com/1/2/3.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/4/5/8.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/10/9/3.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/76/534535/6-1.jpg'
);

$new = array_map(function($v) {
     return preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\/(?=\d)/', '', $v);
}, $my_array);
```

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(25) "http://apinmo.com/123.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(25) "http://apinmo.com/458.jpg"
  [2]=>
  string(26) "http://apinmo.com/1093.jpg"
  [3]=>
  string(33) "http://apinmo.com/765345356-1.jpg"
}
```

And also you can't have `-` in variable names.

**Update**

```
$new = array_map(function($v) {
     $temp = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\/(?=\d)/', '', $v);
     return str_replace('http://', '', $temp);
}, $my_array);

echo implode(', ', $new);
```

**Output**

```
apinmo.com/123.jpg, apinmo.com/458.jpg, apinmo.com/1093.jpg, apinmo.com/765345356-1.jpg
```

Comment: Great it works. I also need to do the same with a string.  Like: $my_string =' http://apinmo.com/1/2/3.jpg, http://apinmo.com/4/5/8.jpg,    http://apinmo.com/10/9/3.jpg, http://apinmo.com/76/534535/6-1.jpg';

Should I create a new question for this?

Comment: I need to make the same replacement but in a string instead of an array. Replace this '$my_string = apinmo.com/1/2/3.jpg, apinmo.com/4/5/8.jpg, apinmo.com/10/9/3.jpg, apinmo.com/76/534535/6-1.jpg'; TO THIS  '$my_NEW_string = apinmo.com/123.jpg, apinmo.com/458.jpg, apinmo.com/1093.jpg, apinmo.com/765345356-1.jpg'; -- Do I need to open a new question for this?

Comment: the update is not working for the string. The input should be a string and the output should  also  be a string.

Comment: Input: $my_string = 'http://apinmo.com/1/2/3.jpg ,other text here,  http://apinmo.com/4/5/8.jpg';

Comment: Output: $my_NEW_string = 'http://apinmo.com/123.jpg ,other text here,  http://apinmo.com/458.jpg';

Comment: Simple `explode(',', $inputString)` them and then apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mya = array(
         'http://apinmo.com/1/2/3.jpg',
         'http://apinmo.com/4/5/8.jpg',
         'http://apinmo.com/10/9/3.jpg',
         'http://apinmo.com/76/534535/6-1.jpg'
    );

    foreach($mya as $my)
    {
        $myb[] = preg_replace("~\/(?!.*\/)~","",preg_replace("~\/(?!.*\/)~", "",$my));
    }

    print_r($myb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regex replace like this:

```
preg_replace("#([0-9\-]+)/([0-9\-]+)/([0-9\-]+).([a-z]+)#", "$1$2$3.$4", $url);
```

Answer (score -1):

simply use pathinfo like this..

```
$my_array = array(
     'http://apinmo.com/1/2/3.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/4/5/8.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/10/9/3.jpg',
     'http://apinmo.com/76/534535/6-1.jpg'
);
$tmp=array();
foreach( $my_array as $url ){
    $tmp[]= pathinfo( $url, PATHINFO_DIRNAME ).pathinfo( $url, PATHINFO_BASENAME );
}
print_r($tmp);
```

Comment: It would not generate the expected result.

Comment: damnit - just notice it should remove all slashes